# Нужна ли запятая и почему?

Tags: запятая

Здравствуйте! Предложение типа:

Как и в любой стране, в нашей есть свои традиции и обычаи.
Как в любом институте, в нашем есть своя учебная программа.

Верно поставлена запятая? Как объяснить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Придаточные сравнительные часто бывают ***неполными предложениями.***
Широкие тени ходят по равнине, как облака по небу (Чехов) – опущено сказуемое ходят.
***Следует отличать неполное придаточное предложение от сравнительного оборота.*** В сравнительном придаточном допускается пропуск сказуемого – оно уже названо в главном предложении (см. пример выше). Так как в придаточном предложении с опущенным сказуемым остаются подлежащее и второстепенные члены, грамматически зависящие от сказуемого (обстоятельство, дополнение), то сказуемое может быть без труда восстановлено.

Ср.: Существование его заключено в эту тесную программу, как яйцо в скорлупу (Чехов). – Существование его заключено в эту тесную программу, как яйцо заключено в скорлупу.

Если в сравнительной конструкции нет членов предложения, зависящих от сказуемого, то она превращается в сравнительный оборот.

Пили бабушкины наливки, жёлтую, как золото, тёмную, как дёготь, и зелёную (М. Горький).[Придаточные сравнительные](http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r2_2_3_1)

***Ваши предложения содержат сравнительную конструкцию, которая зависит от опущенного сказуемого ЕСТЬ: Как [есть] и в любой стране, в нашей есть свои традиции и обычаи. Как [есть] в любом институте, в нашем есть своя учебная программа. Это придаточные сравнительные. Они отделяются запятой.***

Comment: Спасибо, все понятно!

Answer (score 1):

Запятые отделяют придаточное предложение от главного.